# removing first child in web menu

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a menu for a web page and I'm inserting images as menu separators.
maybe this is a little stupid question but I'm trying to remove the first image of my menu
this is my code:

```
.menu ul li {
    background: url(separator.png) no-repeat left;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    height:  50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 155px;
```

and tried this to remove the first separator:

```
   .menu a.first {
         background-image: none;
    }
```

I tried to do what that's in this pages:
http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/uJdhH/1/
http://www.e-blueprint.co.uk/2011/how-to-use-an-image-as-a-menu-separator/

but it don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because your background is on the `li` tag and your `.first` class is on an `anchor` tag you are removing what ever background the anchor holds not the list item.

change to :

```
.menu li.first {
         background-image: none;
    }
```

Comment: you are so right. I was missing that. I already tested and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.menu li:first-child{
     background-image: none;
}
```

Comment: without adding a new class the nth-child element works great, I prefer this one most

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying a background property above for a list item and then removing the background image on the a.first class. You should update .menu class to:

```
    .menu li.first { background:none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you had background to < li > ... then removed background from < a > .. 'Won't work'

```
.menu ul li {
    background: url(separator.png) no-repeat left;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    height:  50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 155px;
```

and tried this to remove the first separator:

```
.menu ul li:first-child {
     background-image: none;
}
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/sd6Vu/